# Значение слова "вертеп"

Tags: этимология, лексика

Изначально "вертеп" - это кукольное изображение яслей, где родился Спаситель. Но почему этим словом стали обозначать еще и бандитский притон или вообще любое гнездо порока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, поможет разобраться статья из АКАДЕМИКА "История слов":

ВЕРТЕП

Слово вертеп — старославянизм по своему происхождению. На это указывает и фонетический облик его (е под ударением перед твердым согласным). Этимология слова считается неясной (Преображенский, 1, с. 76—77). Проф. Г. А. Ильинский находил в этом слове корень *вьрт-. По его мнению, «первоначально оно обозначало не ”пещеру вообще“, а извилистый овраг, пропасть или ущелье» (Ильинский, Слав. этимол. // Изв. ОРЯС АН, 1918, т. 23, кн. 1, с. 165—166). Это значение доныне сохраняется в диалектном украинском (в говоре лемков) слове вертепа и в болгарском врьтопъ — `ущелье с извилинами, кривая балка'. Еще более архаично по значению русское диалектное вертепúжины ж. мн. мск. водороины во множестве, овражистые извилины; сувои, сугробы, раскаты по зимней дороге» (сл. Даля 1880, 1, с. 184). Г. А. Ильинский думал, что отправным пунктом развития значения в этой группе слов было вертѣть. Отсюда могло возникнуть и то значение`водоворота', `поворота по реке' и даже`вихря', которое свойственно, наряду со значеним `ущелье', болгарскому слову врътопъ (ср. украинск. вертепити —`вертеть') (Горяев, Этимол. сл., 1896, с. 45).

По Ильинскому, корень вьрт осложнен в этой группе слов вариантами суффикса -оп- (болг. врътопъ), -еп- (украинск. вертепити) и -ьп- — древнерусск. и старосл. вьртьпъ. Этот суффикс параллелен суффиксу -ьб- (ср. гал.-волынск. вертьбъ; Ев. Церк. XIV в.) и совр. тул. вертебинище (Опыт обл. влкр. сл., с. 23).

Этимологические соображения Г. А. Ильинского очень гадательны. Мало обоснована и предлагаемая им схема развития значений слова вертеп в славянских языках. Сближение с вертеть могло быть продуктом позднейшей народной этимологии. Суффиксы -еп-, -оп-, -ьп- русскому языку неизвестны. Народно-областные значения `овраг, провал, ущелье' тесно связаны со значением`пещера'. Они являются его видоизменением. Понятно, что слово врьтепь не было полным синонимом слова пештера и в старославянском языке.

Ср. в житийной литературе XVI — XVII вв. «изрыть келейцу на брегу сиречь вертепецъ мал» (рукоп. Лен. Публ. Биб. с. 86) (см. И. Некрасов, с. 159). Из этого значения — `укромного убежища' — развивается значение`притон', «подземный или иного устройства скрытный притон» (Даль).

У Пушкина в эпиграфе в 11 гл. «Капитанской дочки», стилизованном под язык Сумарокова:

В ту пору лев был сыт, хоть с роду он свиреп.

«Зачем пожаловать изволил в мой вертеп?»

Спросил он ласково.

У В. В. Капниста в «Видении плачущего над Москвой Россиянина. 1812 г. Окт. 28 дня»:

...Крепило приговор ехидно ябед жало,

И пламя мстительно вертеп неправд пожрало.

Публикуется впервые по сохранившейся в архивных материалах авторской рукописи (5 пожелтевших листков разного формата).

Слово вертеп упоминается В. В. Виноградовым также в работе «А. С. Пушкин — основоположник русского литературного языка». Приведя в качестве примера стилизации пушкинский эпиграф из «Капитанской дочки» (совпадающий с приведенным выше текстом из басни Сумарокова), В. В. Виноградов пишет: «Просторечное сроду и архаическое вертеп в значении `пещера' ведут к басенному стилю Сумарокова» (Изв. АН СССР. Отделение лит-ры и языка. 1949. Т. 8. Вып. 3, с. 204). — Е. X.

В. В. Виноградов. История слов, 2010